# SMS sent from telnet to emulator displayed in weird characters

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, telnet

i try to send an sms from telnet to the emulator

using this command : `sms send (number) (body)`

for some reasons the message sometimes gets viewed in normal english and other times in Chinese characters!

when i try this for example, i get the message perfectly :

```
sms send 123 hey man what's up
```

when i try this, i get Chinese characters:

```
sms send 123 car id =5, latitude = 4343.343, longitude =23112
```

here is my code :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

ArrayList<SmsReceivedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<SmsReceivedListener>();
private static SmsReceivedListener listener;
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null && SMS_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        final SmsMessage smsMessage = extractSmsMessage(intent);

    if(getSmsReceivedListener()!=null)
    {
        String body =  smsMessage.getMessageBody();
        Toast.makeText((Context) context, body, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") private SmsMessage extractSmsMessage(final Intent intent) {

    final Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    final Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    final SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

    return smsMessage;

}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the same problem with the default messaging application during a telnet session.

The problem usually lies in the communication between your telnet client and androids telnet server.

When typing:

```
sms send 123 hello<Enter>
```

right away the message is received correctly.

But if you type:

```
sms send 123 ha<Backspace>ello<Enter>
```

your telnet session will show exactly the same as before, but the message received in the messaging app contains chinese characters. This comes from the  character not being transmitted correctly to the server. Other characters might produce the same problem.